# How to send additional data from controller to resource in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have a controller that I want to do some logic on a variable and send it to resource to show it in api 
so here is my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Accommodation::with('accommodationFacilities')->paginate();
    $x = Accommodation::with('cities')->get(1);

    return new AccommodationResource($data);
}
```

and here is the resource :
and now in the resource I want to show the `$x` in my Api

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

**EDIT**
If I want to show the `$x` data nexto a `$data` model how can i do it like below :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'X'  => $this->x,
    ];
}
```

cause right now it gives me the below error :

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id
>   and when i remove the pagination this error apear :
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

as I tried `$x` replaces the $data and I can't use the data any more.

Comment: Is `->get(1)` meant to be `->find(1)`??

Comment: yes sorry for that mistake its find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to accept additional data to resource, override the `constructor` of the resource.

**AccommodationResource**

```php
public $x;

public function __construct($resource, $x)
{
    parent::__construct($resource);
    $this->x = $x;
}

public function toArray($request)
{
    // you can use '$this->x' here.

    return [
        'id' => $this->resource->id,
        'x' => $this->x,
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```php
return new AccommodationResource($data, $x);
```

Comment: what if i wana show it next to other elements as i can see now it puts the $x variable to $resource and i cant use Accomodation in detail check my edited question please

Comment: You can access `$data` as `$this->resource`. I updated the answer.

Comment: nope again same error i can access it and dd that in contruct but no in toArray($request)

Comment: Now I notice that your `$data` is actually a collection not a single object. So you can't access `id` from a collection. So I have no idea what you are trying to do. If you provide us what is your expected output is, I can help you with your own code. To be honest '__How to send additional data from controller to resource in laravel__' has already answered.

Comment: To be Honest yes you are right :) i want to show all accommodations and along side that in each of them show a custom value thats all